# Express-generator is not working after installing globally

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules, express-generator

I install express generator globally by running

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

after successful installation, I tried to test it by running

```
express -h
```

I got an error saying

```
Cannot find module 'commander' Require stack: - /usr/lib/nodejs/express-generator/bin/express
```

See a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just do npm i
 -g commander to install commander

Comment: I just did that still getting same error when I try running express -h

Comment: Oh... Try with a Yeoman generator, it do the same things better.